# search for duplicate classid in json array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to search for duplicate classids in a json array and for each duplicate found, echo the dulicate id... This is just an example of the json file.

I've tried a few things but failed - if I posted my code it wouldn't work with this sample code. It's a lot more complex as after I am check another json file for matching ids... and a bunch of other stuff.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
"response": {
    "received": [
        {
            "items": [
                {

                    "classid": "356464564",

                },
                {
                    "classid": "456456456",

                },
                {
                    "classid": "356464564",

                },
                {
                    "classid": "721248158",

                }
            ]
            ,
            "time_created": 1440782791,
        },
        {
        "items": [
                {

                    "classid": "845362344",

                },
                {
                    "classid": "2543634754",

                },
                {
                    "classid": "2543634754",

                },
                {
                    "classid": "5967856788",

                }
            ]
            ,
            "time_created": 1440456791,
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please show what you have tried that failed.

Answer (score 0):

This can do what you're looking for:

```
<?php

  $array = json_decode('{
      "response": {
          "received": [
              {
                  "items": [
                      {
                          "classid": "356464564"
                      },
                      {
                          "classid": "456456456"
                      },
                      {
                          "classid": "356464564"
                      },
                      {
                          "classid": "721248158"
                      }
                  ]
                  ,
                  "time_created": 1440782791
              }
          ]
      }
  }', true);

  $cleanArray = array();

  foreach($array['response']['received'][0]['items'] as $classid)
  {
    if(in_array($classid['classid'], $cleanArray))
      echo "Duplicate found: ".$classid['classid'].'<br>';
    else
      $cleanArray[] = $classid['classid'];  
  }

?>
```

Comment: without `true` flag, `$array` will be parsed as `stdClass()`

Comment: you cant echo an array `$classid`

Comment: Also, you need to push the OP to try and show code before providing an answer or else they're basically using you to do their work.

Comment: @CodeGodie, `$classid` are the strings in the `items` sub-array. I wrote the code because it was quite simple, and my intention is to show the OP the general idea, he will have some work to correct possible mistakes I made in the snippet.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, thanks! I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: @Marcovecchio wrong, `$classid` in your code, is an array.

Comment: @CodeGodie is right, `$classid` will output like `array(1) {[classid] => 356464564}`. You should change your `foreach` to `$key=>$value` instead.

Comment: Thank you all, guys! Now I tested the code properly, and the edit I made fixed all issues.

Comment: this : `$cleanArray = array();` is not needed.

Comment: @CodeGodie, I always initialize variables before using them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it makes the array smaller as matches are found, thus making the algorithm more efficient.

```
$arr = json_decode($json , true);
$items_array = array_column($arr['response']['items'], 'classid');

foreach ($items_array as $k => $val) {
    foreach ($items_array as $k2 => $val2) {
        if ($k2 != $k) {
            if ($val == $val2) {
                unset($items_array[$k]);
                if (isset($final[$val])) {
                    $final[$val]++;
                } else {
                    $final[$val] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($final); //will show you your duplicates
```